# Can´t find Form.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have to study a project which was left by another person. It's a Winforms App which displays a form after starting.

I want to access this form in the designer, but can't find the Form.cs file.

I searched all across the project and there are no signs of the ".designer " file of this form.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Above is an image of my solution explorer.

Comment: Why do you think there is a Form.cs file?

Comment: I would look in the `Main` method in `Program.cs` and see what is used there to start the app

Comment: I don't see a form file.  However, for windows forms, you need to right-click on the form file and select "edit code".  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Maybe the previous programmer didn't use a designer.  You can just make a `Form f = new Form();` and add controls yourself to it at runtime.  Seeing the Program.cs file would reveal a lot of information.